# Export-Import issues of hive tables if column datatype doesn't exactly match

Tags: hadoop, hive, google-bigquery, avro

I need to export my existing hive tables having `RCFile` as storage format to hdfs and post that I need to import those data to same set of hive tables having `Avro` as storage format.

Since,Avro doesn't support `timestamp` and `decimal` types. Therefore, I need to use `String` and `Float` datatypes respectively for those columns. This approach brings some mismatch between the exported and to be imported hive table schemas.
I tried importing one of the existing hive tables but couldn't import the data successfully due to schema mismatch issue.

I'm thinking about developing an automated approach which will allow defined set of Bigquery tables to be loaded by their corresponding `Avro` source files. Now, those files should be available in `GCS` buckets. This availability will be ensured by a part of my automated process which will allow loading of same set of `External` Hive tables having `Avro` as the storage format and `GCS Bucket` as the storage location.

So the entire process can be summarised like this:
Table A in Hive-> Export to HDFS location-> Import to Table B in Hive having Avro as storage type and GCS as storage location->Loading of Bigquery Table C with the Avro file generated in previous step

Is there any way which allows this export-import mechanism work properly regardless of these datatype mismatches?

Comment: I'm confused by this part: _"I need to import the data in external hive tables in Avro format as I have to load my target Bigquery tables reading the data from external GCS location."_. What exactly is the question?

Comment: Apologies for not providing my information on this. I have edited my question with detailed approach.

Comment: Can you clarify this comment: "Since,Avro doesn't support timestamp and decimal types. Therefore, I need to use String and Float datatypes respectively for those columns. "

Avro does have native understanding of both types as Avro logical types: https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.0/spec.html#Logical+Types.

BigQuery now also understands these logical types natively: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-avro#logical_types when you load them.

Given this, will you still have an issue?